# The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" has not been registered

Tags: sql-server-2005, openrowset

I'd like to extract data from a .csv file. I cannot use OpenRowSet on a 64-bit machine because it says:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" has not been registered.
```

and there is no MSDASQL entry in the **Linked Servers -> Providers** section of the SQL Server 2005 SSMS the same way 32-bit ones have.

Can someone suggest a comparable method to extract data from a .csv file?

Comment: That is true- sorry about that.

Comment: Can you install the 64 bit pack?

Comment: Not without testing, waiting, and so forth. I would imagine something as simplistic & trivial as extracting csv file contents to a temp table is doable without the need to perform anything beyond SQL Functions. I hate involving infrastructural work, installational work, remote desktop work, and any non-computer-programming in my tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use `OPENROWSET` to extract data from a .csv file on a 64-bit computer. You railroad through a 32-bit computer, here called `LinkedServer32Bit`, via `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
(
    LinkedServer32Bit, 
   'Select * FROM OPENROWSET 
    (
       ''MSDASQL'', 
       ''Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; 
         DefaultDir=C:\z\;'', 
       ''SELECT y FROM x.csv''
    )'
)
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to fix your environment?

Comment: No, because it involves contacting people beyond the scope of SQL Programming.

Comment: According to http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForODBCDatabases, that OLE DB provided is considered obsolete by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Are both servers 64 bit?

You have you install [64-Bit OLEDB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=000364db-5e8b-44a8-b9be-ca44d18b059b&displaylang=en). We did to get our linked servers working (non-SQL Server). [And more info here](http://blogs.msdn.com/data/archive/2008/04/07/64-bit-oledb-provider-for-odbc-msdasql-is-now-available-for-windows-server-2003.aspx)

If not 64 bit, then it could be an OS corruption because it's just *there* on 32 bit Windows.

Edit:

Have you actually checked if the servers are 64 bit, or the broken one is, using `select @@version`, or simply ignoring potential fixes based on personal experience and knowledge...?